# JQuery sliding one table form out and the other slide in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm have two table forms (Each of them is in a div with class 'box') I'm trying to use jquery animation to move one form out of the screen, and move the other one in, and then when that button is clicked again, the original form comes back from where it was moved. Here's the HTML for one of the forms (both of them are almost identical, the other one has an id of 'box2').

```
<a href="#" class="button" style="margin-top: 0px; height: 15px;">Click here to edit!</a>
<div class="box1" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <form name="getinfo" onSubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST" action="process.php">
        <table class="info" cellpadding="10px">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right; font-size: 13px;">First Name:</td>
            <td id="trfname"><input name="fname" class="infod" type="input" /></td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right; font-size: 13px;">Last Name:</td>
            <td id="trlname"><input name="lname" class="infod" type="input" /></td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right; font-size: 13px;">Cascade:</td>
            <td id="trcascade"><input name="cascade" class="infod" type="input" /></td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is the code I'm trying, but it doesn't seem to be working. No console errors.

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index(".button");
    var $box = $(".box:eq(" + index + ")");

    $(".box").not($box).animate({
        left: '150%'
    }, 500);

    if ($box.offset().left < 0) {
        $box.css("left", "150%");
    } else if ($box.offset().left > $('#main').width()) {
        $box.animate({
            left: '50%',
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Edit: full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/vCguL/

Comment: I only see one `box`. Please create a jsFiddle with all relevant codde.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame just added it to the bottom. hope it helps.

Comment: Start by validating your code. You have so many unclosed mismatched tags its a crap shoot to work with. Then repost the cleaned up html to the fiddle.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame http://jsfiddle.net/vCguL/8/ I made a simplified version, with all of my classes and Ids. Its much easier to read now.

Comment: [Done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11351724/144665). Using the toggle event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/d4Ruz/

jQuery

```
$(function(){

    $('a.button').toggle(function() {
        $('#box1').animate({'left':'-400px'});
        $('#box2').css({'left':'400px'}).animate({'left':'0'});
    },function() {
        $('#box1').css({'left':'400px'}).animate({'left':'0'});
        $('#box2').animate({'left':'-400px'});
    });

});​
```